# Can anybody explain to me what's the problem? And how solution is?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, crystal-reports-2010

Failed to retrieve data from the database.  Details: [Database Vendor Code: 1064] Failed to retrieve data from the database.  Error in File temp_fd14fd01-8449-4297-a5ee-8c0d0dba45ca {E3726659-1FFA-4DC0-A772-11D0EC0EA27D}.rpt: Failed to retrieve data from the database.  Details: [Database Vendor Code: 1064]

Comment: My database using Mysql

Comment: [This resource](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/database-troubleshooting/error-1064) speaks to a possible cause for this error, suggesting that there's an error with your SQL statement. Please review then post your SQL statement as an edit to your question so we can help you identity the problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Ricky. Your question is likely to be closed, because you haven't provided sufficient information for anybody to provide an answer. When I ask a question here, I keep a browser window open to it, so if other members ask for clarification, I can quickly respond.

Comment: SELECT datagejala.Gejala, gejala.Bobot, hasil.Id Pasien, hasil.Nama Penyakit, hasil.Tanggal, pasien.Nama, pasien.Jenis Kelamin, pasien.Usia, hasil.Solusi
 FROM   gejala gejala INNER JOIN ((pasien pasien INNER JOIN hasil hasil ON pasien.Id Pasien=hasil.Id Pasien) INNER JOIN datagejala datagejala ON pasien.Id Pasien=datagejala.Id Pasien) ON gejala.Kode=datagejala.Gejala